# Subgroup of size p p=prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Are subgroups of size $p$ where $p$ is prime, cyclic subgroups? I understand that if the group $G$ is prime order, then $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: Well, if you alreay know that every group of prime orde is cyclic, and that every subgroup of a group is itself a group, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any group $G$ of order $p,$ where $p$ is a prime number is a cyclic group. Too see this: 
Let $g$ be an element in $G$ other than $e$, and consider the cyclic subgroup generated by $g$. 
This subgroup $\langle g\rangle $ has more than $1$ element, and use Lagrange theorem we have: $|\langle g\rangle|$ divides $|G|=p$. So $|\langle g\rangle| = 1$ or $p$, and since $\langle g\rangle$ has more than $1$ elements, it must be that $|\langle g\rangle| = p$. Since $\langle g\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$ with the same order as $G$, $G = \langle g\rangle,$ showing $G$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

according to Lagrange's theorem the size of every subgroup of a finite group divides the group. In other words: if h is a subgroup of g than $|g|/|h| \epsilon N $. Now... because $|g|=p$ while p is prime than the only possible subgroups of g have the size $1$ and the size $p$: the only possible thing is that the subgroups are: $$g, <0>$$
and these two groups are cyclic